# Fixing <right arrow> in bash vi input mode. Cannot type beyond last character

Tags: bash, macos, vi, readline, arrow-keys

I'm trying to use vi mode in bash. via the .inputrc (on OSX):

```
set editing-mode vi
```

In vi insert mode, the right arrow key moves the cursor to the right, but it stops on the last character in the line.  If the cursor is past the end of the line, it moves the cursor to the *left*.  So, in sum, the farthest right you can go is to the last character in the line.

```
$ cd /usr/locl/bin
# Move the cursor to the middle of the line, and fix something there
$ cd /usr/local/bin
# Now move the cursor back to the end, and write a character (/)
$ cd /usr/local/bi/n
```

As shown above this means you cannot edit the end of the line without going into command mode (and using 'a').

I found an article which seems to indicate the version of readline/bash [might be the problem](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-readline/2009-06/msg00014.html). However I used brew to upgrade bash (GNU bash, version 4.3.42), and even tried to install and link readline (6.3.8), as recommend by that site. But no luck. Its possible the upgrade was done incorrectly.

### This means I'm looking for one of the following:

- The proper way to upgrade bash and readline in OSX terminal
- A way to check the versions of bash/readline that OSX is actually using
- Another fix for this bug (somehow passing in the virtualedit=onemore option in the inputrc)
- Indications that the latest versions of readline might have re-introduced the bug, and solutions.
- Also: if theres a similar thing with editrc

*Note:* I'm looking to make readline in bash act near identical to the default (for others who periodically use my terminal), but allow me to use vim mode. This means I don't need workarounds, but fixes.

Comment: Shell scripting questions are perfectly on-topic here, but shell *usage* questions are better on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/

Comment: should I move it over then? if so how? (I'm a bit new to the UI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you edit .bashrc itself instead to use vi mode? The command `set -o vi` does it in my case (you are in edit mode initially). Also remove the .inputrc edit as the two may actually interact nefariously afterwards.

Comment: I am using Vi mode. the problem occurs when in VI insert mode.

Comment: I was asking to change what offered the vi mode (namely, it should be Bash, not the terminal itself, that provides the vi mode)

Comment: That did work, though I would like to ask for clarification as to the difference. Bash uses a different readline program? or is it that the terminal (OSX) will always use the inbuilt readline which has this bug, and has no way to change it?
Secondly this won't affect other programs that use readline, e.g. interactive interpreters? If so is there a way to change the terminal default too?

Comment: The terminal itself is buggy, as you have already noticed (if it weren't, you wouldn't have even posted this question)

Comment: I can confirm OS X 10.9.5 does NOT have this bug (Hackintosh, cannot upgrade)

Answer (score 2):

Answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/222506/198846

Apparently it's a bug in the bash version shipped with OSX (3.2), it's fixed in 4.3 according to that answer. Use `bash --version` to check your bash version.

To fix, update bash, e.g.

macports: `sudo port install bash`

brew: `brew install bash`

Once installed `bash --version` will show it's updated (assuming standard brew/macports paths at the start of your $PATH)

You then have to change your default login shell (in System Preferences->Users & Groups->right click your user->advanced options->login shell) to the path of the new bash:

(default) macports: `/opt/local/bin/bash`

(default) brew: `/usr/local/bin/bash`

Changing the default login shell step is required even if `which bash` shows the macports/brew one.

All credit to the answer linked above.